# Como empregar multithreading com arduino

Tags: multithreading, arduino

Estou fazendo uma campainha com arduino. 
Esta campainha será composta de:

- 01 Arduino UNO,
- 01 Buzzer,
- 01 Transmissor 433 Mhz,
- 01 Receptor 433 Mhz.

A minha dúvida gira em torno de como posso tratar o listener que ficará escutando 
os comandos dos controle 433 Mhz e ao mesmo tempo fazer o tratamento para
que o buzzer oscile utilizando delays.

Meu código é basicamente este. Estou usando a biblioteca RFremote que encontrei neste link https://github.com/renatoaloi/RFremote

```
#include <RFremote.h>
SignalPatternParams params;
RFrecv rfrecv;

int status_prog = 0;

const int buzzer = 11;
const char *BOTAO1 = "0100100100110110110100100110110100100110110110110110100100110100100110100100110100110";
const char *BOTAO3 = "0100100100110110110100100110110100100110110110110110100100110100100100110100110100110";

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(500);

  Serial.println("INICIADO!");

  // COMPATEC remote
  params.spaceMin = 10000;
  params.spaceMax = 15000;
  params.dotMin = 450;
  params.dotMax = 600;
  params.traceMin = 950;
  params.traceMax = 1150;
  params.skipFirst = 0;
  params.skipLast = 0;

  rfrecv = RFrecv(&params);
  rfrecv.begin();

  pinMode(buzzer,OUTPUT);

}

void loop()
{

  if (rfrecv.available()) // LISTENER DO CONTROLE - RECEBE ID DO CONTROLE/TECLA VIA FREQUENCIA 433 Mhz
  {
    if (strncmp((char*)rfrecv.cmd, BOTAO1, CMD_SIZE) == 0) { 
      status_prog = 1; // LIGA O BUZZER
    }
    if (strncmp((char*)rfrecv.cmd, BOTAO3, CMD_SIZE) == 0) {
      status_prog = 3; // DESLIGA O BUZZER
    }
  }

  if(status_prog == 1) {  // SE O BOTÃO PRESSIONADO FOR EQUIVALENTE A 1 LIGA
      tone(buzzer, 650); // ACIONA BUZZER COM A TONALIDADE 650
      delay(400);        // PAUSA POR 400 MS
      noTone(buzzer);    // DESLIGA BUZZER
      delay(400);        // PAUSA POR 400 MS
  }

  if(status_prog == 3){ 
    noTone(buzzer);      // SE O BOTÃO PRESSIONADO FOR EQUIVALENTE A 3 DESLIGA
  }

}
```

Se eu retirar o delay nesta parte

```
if(status_prog == 1) {  // SE O BOTÃO PRESSIONADO FOR EQUIVALENTE A 1 LIGA
   tone(buzzer, 650); // ACIONA BUZZER COM A TONALIDADE 650
   //delay(400);        // PAUSA POR 400 MS
   //noTone(buzzer);    // DESLIGA BUZZER
   //delay(400);        // PAUSA POR 400 MS
}
```

o programa funciona corretamente.

Penso que o `delay(400)` acaba tomando o tempo que o programa como um todo tem para escutar o controle. Qual seria a abordagem a tomar neste caso? Uma Thread seria bem vinda...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O Arduino não suporta multithreading, mas já ouvi falar de bibliotecas que simulam isso. Porém, o mais simples é não usar delays (que realmente deixam o programa "surdo e mudo"), e calcular se está na hora de ligar ou desligar o *buzzer* com base no tempo decorrido desde que o programa começou a rodar (usando a função `millis()`). Algo assim (não testado):

```
bool oscilando = false;
bool tocando = false
long comeco = 0;
long intervalo = 400;

void loop()
{
  unsigned long agora = millis();

  if (rfrecv.available()) // LISTENER DO CONTROLE - RECEBE ID DO CONTROLE/TECLA VIA FREQUENCIA 433 Mhz
  {
    if (strncmp((char*)rfrecv.cmd, BOTAO1, CMD_SIZE) == 0) { 
      oscilando = true;
      tocando = false;
      comeco = agora;
    }
    if (strncmp((char*)rfrecv.cmd, BOTAO3, CMD_SIZE) == 0) {
      oscilando = false;
      tocando = false;
      noTone(buzzer);
    }
  }

  if(oscilando && agora - comeco > intervalo) {
      tocando = !tocando;
      comeco = agora;
      if(tocando) {
          tone(buzzer, 650);
      } else {
          noTone(buzzer);
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Para complementar um pouco a [resposta do @bfavaretto sobre Mult-task no Arduino](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/49986/8039)

O Arduino pode vir a suportar multtasking (Multitarefa) com base em time-sharing, mesmo nos controladores AVR que são 8 bits, porém isso somente é aplicável em códigos muito simples e se a atividade demandar cálculos e controles e tempo real, mas sem dúvida o ideal é usar um Arduino DUE caso realmente preciso de Multtask, eu comecei alguns estudos com o FreeRTOS e cheguei ao DuinOS, fiz inclusive um fork e algumas atualizações mas por falta de tempo parei.

O uso d RTOS mesmo em arquitetura 8bits ajuda muito em tarefas que demandam um bom sincronismo para acionar portas e ler portas desde que sejam tarefas e cálculos simples. É possível rodar inclusive no Arduino UNO até 3 tarefas básicas, vamos supor leitura alguns medidores de nível, acionar bombas de forma que tudo funcione em três blocos de controle independentes ou sincronizados.

A vantagem muitas vezes é se ter um melhor sincronismo e como diz, RTOS, nos traz resultados em tempo real, o que elimina o uso de funções como `delay()` e reduz a simplicidade do código na camada relativa a lógica de se`processo, eliminando diversas variáveis de controle de tempo, como usado quando se quer eliminar o uso do`delay()`;